# Ask for existing subnet group in AWS CloudFormation script

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a CloudFormation script that creates an RDS instance and asks for a Subnet Group. But instead of making the user specify the subnets one by one and create a new group, I want to select an existing group.

Right now I have this for the subnet group:

```
    "DatabaseSubnets": {
        "Description": "The subnets to place database instances in.",
        "Type": "List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>"
    },
    ....
    "DatabaseSubnetGroup": {
        "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup",
        "Properties": {
            "DBSubnetGroupDescription": "CloudFormation managed DB subnet group.",
            "SubnetIds": {
                "Ref": "DatabaseSubnets"
            }
        }
    },
```

How do I change it to select an existing group? Should I replace the `"Properties"` group with a `Ref`?

Answer (score 2):

The type is specified incorrectly. Try this:

```
"DatabaseSubnets": {
    "Description": "The subnets to place database instances in.",
    "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id"
    "Default" : ""
},
```

Comment: The type is a list of subnets, because I need at least 2 subnets for an RDS.

Answer (score 1):

If the subnets are created outside of this Cloudformation template then what you're doing would be the best approach. The alternative would be to hardcode the subnets which is less ideal than passing them in as a parameter.

Alternatively if you're creating the subnets within the same Cloudformation template you could reference them but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: I was more thinking about passing a Subnet Group ID as a parameter.

Comment: DBSubnetGroup only accepts subnet ids. See here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-rds-dbsubnet-group.html

If you want to re-use an existing one for your RDS then you can pass it in via the DBSubnetGroupName parameter: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-rds-dbcluster.html#cfn-rds-dbcluster-dbsubnetgroupname and http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html#cfn-rds-dbinstance-dbsubnetgroupname